# Binding doesn't work even with NotifyPropertyCHanged

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

Hie everyone, I'm currently works on a project with Xamarin Forms. I'll try to put context for helping you to understand.

I have a class called "Prestation" which contains a list of object called "Temps". According to my object "Prestation", I will have at the beginning multiple object "Temps" and I want to be able to edit each line of my "Temps" objects. For that, I use a DXCollectionView and put my Time inside this one. WHen I click on one of my object, a popup appear and I can change the value ( which are Begin time and End time ). But when I submit, the page **doesn't refresh**. I hope to be clear, please find my code below.

Class for helping refresh

```cs
public class NotificationData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, Action onChanged = null, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;

            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Part of my ViewModel

```
public class DossierPageVM : NotificationData
    {
        private App MyApp { get; set; }
        public Bon Bon { get; set; }

        private Temps tempsActuelle;
        public Temps TEMPSACTUELLE
        {
            get => this.tempsActuelle;
            set => this.SetProperty(ref this.tempsActuelle, value);
        }

        private IList<Prestation> _dataPresta;
        public IList<Prestation> DataPresta
        {
            get => this._dataPresta;
            set => SetProperty(ref this._dataPresta, value);
        }

        private IList<Emballage> _dataEmbal;
        public IList<Emballage> DataEmbal
        {
            get => this._dataEmbal;
            set => SetProperty(ref this._dataEmbal, value);
        }

        bool isOpenPopupTemps;
        public bool IsOpenPopupTemps
        {
            get => this.isOpenPopupTemps;
            set => SetProperty(ref this.isOpenPopupTemps, value);
        }

        string popupTempsTitle;
        public string PopupTempsTitle
        {
            get => this.popupTempsTitle;
            set => SetProperty(ref this.popupTempsTitle, value);
        }

        public DossierPageVM(Bon bon)
        {
            this.VALIDERSIGNATAIRE = this.VALIDERPRESTA = false;
            if ( bon != null )
            {
                _dataPresta = new List<Prestation>();
                this.MyApp = ((App)Application.Current);
                DataPresta = bon.PRESTATIONS;
                
                this.Bon = bon;
                this.IsOpenPopupTemps = false;
                RefreshCommand = new Command(ExecuteRefreshCommand);
            }
        }

        ICommand refreshCommand = null;
        public ICommand RefreshCommand
        {
            get => this.refreshCommand;
            set => SetProperty(ref this.refreshCommand, value);
        }

        public void ExecuteRefreshCommand()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                List<Prestation> prestations = new List<Prestation>(this.Bon.PRESTATIONS);
                DataPresta = prestations;

            });
        }
    }
```

Part of my View ( what it should be interresting for this problem )

```
        private void Temps_Tap(object sender, CollectionViewGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Model.PopupTempsTitle = "Modification d'un temps";
            this.Model.TEMPSACTUELLE = (Temps)e.Item;
            this.Model.IsOpenPopupTemps = true;
        }

        private void ValiderPopupTemps(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null && this.Model.TEMPSACTUELLE != null)
            {
                if (this.Model.TEMPSACTUELLE.DTE_FIN.Subtract(this.Model.TEMPSACTUELLE.DTE_DEBUT).TotalMilliseconds < 0)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IDeviceDependency>().ShortAlert("Saisissez une heure de fin supérieure à l'heure du début");
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Model.TEMPSACTUELLE.DUREE_PRESTA = TimeSpan.Parse(this.Model.TEMPSACTUELLE.DTE_FIN.Subtract(TimeSpan.Parse(this.Model.TEMPSACTUELLE.DTE_DEBUT.ToString("HH:mm"))).ToString("HH:mm")).TotalHours;
                    this.MyApp.Database.ModifTemps(this.bon, this.Model.TEMPSACTUELLE);
                    this.Model.ExecuteRefreshCommand();
                    this.Model.IsOpenPopupTemps = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

And xaml code ( what it should be interesting )

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplateFinishPrestation">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                             Margin="12,0,12,0">

                                    <Grid HeightRequest="45">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        
                                        <Label Text="{Binding TYP_PRESTA}"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                                               TextColor="Black"
                                               Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                        <dxe:SimpleButton Text="Reprendre"
                                                          TextColor="White"
                                                          FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                          BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource ClassicBlue}"
                                                          VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                          Clicked="AjouterPresta"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </Grid>

                                    <Label LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                           Text="{Binding CDE_PRESTA}"
                                           TextColor="Black"/>

                                    <dxcv:DXCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding TEMPS}"
                                                           ReduceSizeToContent="True"
                                                           Tap="Temps_Tap"
                                                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShowTime}">
                                    </dxcv:DXCollectionView>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <BoxView  Style="{DynamicResource SeparatorStyle}" Margin="60,4,60,4"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>


                        <DataTemplate x:Key="ShowTime">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label TextColor="Black"
                                        Text="{Binding DTE_DEBUT,StringFormat='Début: {0:HH:mm}  ', FallbackValue='Début: ...'}"/>
                                <Label TextColor="Black"
                                       Text="{Binding  DTE_FIN,StringFormat='Fin: {0:HH:mm}  ', FallbackValue='Fin: ...'}"/>
                                <Label TextColor="Black"
                                       Text="{Binding  DUREE_PRESTA_TEMP,StringFormat='Duree: {0:HH:mm}  ', FallbackValue='Fin: ...'}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

```xml
<dxp:DXPopup AllowScrim="True"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            CornerRadius="16"
                                             IsOpen="{Binding IsOpenPopupTemps}"
                                             x:Name="PopupTemps">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding PopupTempsTitle}"
                                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource TextThemeColor}"
                                                Margin="24,16,24,14"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        
                                        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}" Margin="24,0"/>

                                        <dxe:TimeEdit LabelText="Début"
                                                      x:Name="HDEBUT"
                                                      Style="{StaticResource ChangeHeurePresta}"
                                                      Time="{Binding TEMPSACTUELLE.DTE_DEBUT, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                                        <dxe:TimeEdit LabelText="Fin"
                                                      x:Name="HFIN"
                                                      Style="{StaticResource ChangeHeurePresta}"
                                                      Time="{Binding TEMPSACTUELLE.DTE_FIN, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                        
                                        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}" Margin="24,0"/>

                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            
                                            <dxe:SimpleButton Text="Valider"
                                                              Grid.Column="0"
                                                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                          TextColor="{DynamicResource ClassicGreen}"
                                                          PressedBackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainPageBackgroundColor}"
                                                          BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                          Clicked="ValiderPopupTemps"
                                                          Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </dxp:DXPopup>
```

Comment: if the user is modify property `X` of Class `C`, `C` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and the setter for `X` need to call `PropertyChanged` .  Since you didn't post the code for `Temps` I can't verify if you are actually doing this

Comment: Thx, It's working, I use my class **NotificationData** as base class in **Prestation**, set my List<Temps> with SetProperty and in my function for Refresh I pass through all the List<Temps> from all my Prestation object and set them. So it's working

Answer (score 0):

Good news, the problem is solve.
So, this is what I done to fix it.

As it says in comment, "if the user is modify property X of Class C, C must implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and the setter for X need to call PropertyChanged".

Indeed, I call `PropertyChanged` on my `List<Prestation>` which contains a `List<Temps>`. However, I didn't call `PropertyChanged` on the attribute of my differents objects `Temps`.

So, to solve my problem I put something like this on each of my attribute which needed synchronisation with binding.

Here an example

```
private int myAttributes;
public int MYATTRIBUTES
{
    get => this.myAttributes;
    set => this.SetProperty(ref this.myAttributes, value);
}
```

Thx for helping everyone.
Cheers